# Do microprocessors disable interrupts while compare and swap instructions are executed?

Tags: c++, embedded, cpu, atomic, microprocessors

Does the 1.4 GHz Intel Core i5 (64 bit) CPU disable interrupts, when [compare and swap instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) is executing?

In other words if I have `std::atomic<int> atom_int;`, does that mean during `atom_int++;` the signals (`SIGINT`, `SIGSTP`, `SIGKILL`) cannot be delivered to the process?

I understand its CPU specific question and was hoping to get answer for any specific CPU.

Comment: I think on intel it is implemented as a single instruction so can't be interrupted?

Comment: This is unanswerable as there is no standard for how all CPUs are architected.  Also, this is not part of the C++ specification, so I'm not sure why c++ is tagged with this question at all.

Comment: Did you try to look at the generated assembly for your target system? If you don't have a certain target, please tell us the range of systems you mean.

Comment: However, I would expect the behavior you're describing. Otherwise the *atomic* attribute makes no sense.

Comment: This is a weird mix of a CPU-specific question about Intel CPUs and a C++ language question about receiving signals during operations on `std::atomic` types. You ask one question, then say "in other words", and then ask a completely different question. What does how the CPU handles interrupts during single instructions have to do with receiving a signal that may or may not be delivered by an interrupt and code that may or may not be implemented with a single instruction?

Comment: Interrupts and signals are not the same thing.  You have conflated the two.

Comment: @Clifford: If a signal causes the kernel to send an interrupt to the CPU running the process (which I believe most modern operating systems do), then, for the purpose of the question, they can be considered identical. However, you are still right that it was worth mentioning that they are not the same thing.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel :  Most embedded systems are not necessarily running such an operating system - it is not really a matter of "modern".  To be fair most embedded systems are not running on an i5 either.  I am not familiar with Linux kernel details but I think the terms have been used ambiguously in this question - looks like a conflation of several concepts at very different levels of abstraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following two things are not necessarily the same:

1. Atomic operations on a C++ level (std::atomic)
2. Assembler CPU instructions that are guaranteed to be atomic

For example, a modern Intel processor guarantees that 64-bit reads/writes to a 64-bit aligned address is atomic. It also guarantees that an instruction with a LOCK prefix is executed atomically.

In C++, on the other hand, `std::atomic` guarantees that an operation on an object is executed atomically. A good compiler will use a single atomic CPU instructions for this, if possible. However, for larger objects, this atomicity cannot be accomplished with a single atomic CPU instruction. Therefore, atomicity can only be guaranteed by using more complex synchronization methods, such as [locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)). Such complex synchronization methods require several CPU instructions and can therefore always be interrupted.

You can determine whether `std:atomic` is using locks or not by calling [`std::atomic::is_lock_free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free).

Answer (score 3):

Intel CPUs (effectively) disable interrupts while ALL instructions are executing -- interrupts can only be delivered *between* instructions.  Now the execution of instruction may overlap in time (confusing what is meant by *between*), but the way the interrupt mechanism works, every instruction before the interrupt will complete, while every instruction after the interrupt will be cancelled (so have no effect).

Note that just because an interrupt cannot be delivered in the middle of an instruction, that does not make an instruction *atomic* if the instruction contains more than one memory access (such as a `inc mem` that effectively does a read-modify-write), as other CPUs or other devices connected to the bus may modify the location in between.  That's what the `lock` prefix is for -- it guarentees that nothing else can happen to that memory location while the instruction is running.

Comment: I didn't realize its a single instruction! Now it makes sense

Comment: I believe this answer is misleading. Although the OP was a bit unclear whether he was referring to CPU instructions or std::atomic operations, at one point, he specifically asked whether an std::atomic operation can be interrupted. As I have shown in my answer, this is possible, if the compiler is unable to implement the std::atomic operation as a single CPU instruction (for example if the object is too large).

Comment: While it may or may not be what the OP was asking for, I was careful to be clear I was talking about instructions on an Intel CPU, not any abstract C++ object.

Comment: @ChrisDodd There are instructions that can be interrupted during execution and pick up where they left off. These include long-running instructions like `REP MOVSB` and `VPGATHERQD`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: while technically true, those instructions still act as though 'between' as when an interrupt happens inside them, they need to be "restarted" (refetched and redecoded) when the interrupt continues.  In particular, however, they can't be combined with a lock prefix to be made atomic.